# how can I unpack click apps?

Tags: package-management, files, click-packages

i have a click app from the open store `https://open-store.io/app/activitytracker.cwayne18` 
this app is packaged for ubuntu touch, but I just want to decompress it, and read the source code. Gdebi allows for this, but the interface sucks.

I tried decompressing it with engrampa, but it is an unrecognized format.hiw can I unpack the click file type?

Alternatively, a method of converting a click apt to a deb package would be fine, as I can open deb files easily.

Comment: `$ cd [new empty directory]/ && wget https://open-store.io/api/v3/apps/activitytracker.cwayne18/download/xenial/all && mv all activitytracker.cwayne18.deb` .... Open the package: `$ dpkg -x activitytracker.cwayne18.deb ./` .......... Please note : **No source code** in packages which can be installed.

Comment: Ref. https://open-store.io/app/activitytracker.cwayne18 → → Download >>> Copy Link Location

Comment: Found the source code : Google, cwayne activitytracker github → https://github.com/cwayne18 → → → https://github.com/cwayne18/ActivityTracker